# Table leaves page and won't compile

Tags: tables

I am writing a table and it keeps leaving the page.

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
    \hline
    \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Problem} & \textbf{Fix} \\
    \hline
    \multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{Inconsistency}} & cell & \textbf{cell} \\ \cline{2-3}
    & cell. & cell6 \\ \cline{2-3}
    & cell8 & cell9 \\ \cline{2-3}
    & cell8 & cell9 \\ \cline{2-3}
    & cell8 & cell9 \\ \cline{2-3}
    & cell8 & cell9 \\ \cline{2-3}
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Whenever I fill up the cells, the table stretches to the right of the page. I resorted to using instead a table builder which generated this:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[]
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \textbf{Type}                           & \textbf{Problem}                                                                                                          & \textbf{Fix}                                                                                                                                                                 \\
    \multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{Inconsistency}} & Some records have missing data for all UPDRS-III variables.                                                               & Remove these records                                                                                                                                                         \\
                                            & A few records have PDSTATE=ON and PDTRTMNT=0, which is inconsistent:                                                      & Set PDTRTMNT=1 for these records. It doesn't seem realistic that a plausible PDMEDTM and PDSTATE=ON have been entered by mistake while the patient was not under medication. \\
                                            & Some records have a non-empty PDMEDTM and have PDTRTMNT=0, which is inconsistent.                                         & Set PDTRTMNT=1. It is unlikely that a plausible medication time was entered by mistake.                                                                                      \\
                                            & Some patients were on medication at screening time while PPMI patients were supposed to be unmedicated at screening time. & \textbf{Keep the records. Maybe the patients started medication between recruitment and screening time.}                                                                     \\
                                            & Some records have PDSTATE=ON but PDMEDTM is after EXAMTM.                                                                 & \textbf{Discard the records.}                                                                                                                                                \\
                                            & Some visits have 3 exams while a maximum of two exams per visit are expected, one in OFF state and one in ON state.       & Remove exam with EXAMTM=NaN and PDSTATE=NaN  when visit has 3 exams                                                                                                          \\
                                            &                                                                                                                           &
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, I get these errors:

[image]

EDIT: Document class

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\include{config}
\include{constants}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\include{pages/abstract}
\include{pages/acknowledgements}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Body of Thesis goes here.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%To inlcude new chapter add "\include{chapters/chapter-no/chapter-no.tex"
\include{chapters/chapter1/chapter1}
\include{chapters/chapter2/chapter2}
\include{chapters/chapter3/chapter3}
\include{chapters/chapter4/chapter4}
\include{chapters/chapter5/chapter5}

% Appendix
\appendix
\include{chapters/appendix/appendix}

%You can edit your citation style by changing the name in \bibliographystyle{plain} --> \bibliographystyle{new style name}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
%Add the bibilography file name below
\bibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to show the entire code from `\documentclass{}` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome. // Have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx . It‘s similar, you specify an overall width and replace on of you c‘s with a X.

Comment: I added the entire document code @User23456234

Comment: Your code is not compilable. Be aware, that we not have your files nor interested f0por the. Make from your code fragments one small complete document, which show your problem. And clariffy, how many tables you have and how they should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I only focused on the table since it has been a subject for your question.*

The reason why the table is extended beyond the page is length of your the text and `l`-type column, which does not wrap texts if it exceeds page boundaries. One solution is to apply `p{width}` (and its variations, s.a. `m{}` or `b{}`) to create fixed columns, which does wrap longer texts.

Additionally, in your approach, the table has 3 columns. The first column contains only one line of a long text taking significant space, which can be used by the other two columns since they contain long paragraphs. I would move the word "Inconsistency" to the top and arrange Problem/Fix in separate rows.

"Inconsistency" can be rotated reducing size of the first column and keeping everything similar to your original layout. You might consider rendering the whole table vertically; simply change `table[tbh]` environment to `sidewaystable` (requires to load `rotating`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.7cm}X}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Inconsistency}} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \textbf{Problem:} & Some records have missing data for all UPDRS-III variables. \\
    \textbf{Fix:}     & Remove these records \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Problem:} & A few records have PDSTATE=ON and PDTRTMNT=0, which is inconsistent: \\
    \textbf{Fix:}     & Set PDTRTMNT=1 for these records. It doesn't seem realistic that a plausible PDMEDTM and PDSTATE=ON have been entered by mistake while the patient was not under medication. \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Problem:} & Some records have a non-empty PDMEDTM and have PDTRTMNT=0, which is inconsistent. \\
    \textbf{Fix:}     & Set PDTRTMNT=1. It is unlikely that a plausible medication time was entered by mistake. \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Problem:} & Some patients were on medication at screening time while PPMI patients were supposed to be unmedicated at screening time. \\
    \textbf{Fix:}     & \textbf{Keep the records. Maybe the patients started medication between recruitment and screening time.} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Problem:} & Some records have PDSTATE=ON but PDMEDTM is after EXAMTM. \\
    \textbf{Fix:}     & \textbf{Discard the records.} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Problem:} & Some visits have 3 exams while a maximum of two exams per visit are expected, one in OFF state and one in ON state. \\
    \textbf{Fix:}     & Remove exam with EXAMTM=NaN and PDSTATE=NaN  when visit has 3 exams \\
    % & &
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\begin{table}[tbh]
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \captionsetup{skip=3pt}
  \centering
  \caption{The table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cXX@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Type}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Problem}} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multirow{12}*[-5\normalbaselineskip]{\rotatebox{90}{$\xmathstrut[0.35]{0}$\textbf{Inconsistency}}}
    & Some records have missing data for all UPDRS-III variables.
    & Remove these records \\ \cmidrule{2-3}
    & A few records have PDSTATE=ON and PDTRTMNT=0, which is inconsistent:
    & Set PDTRTMNT=1 for these records. It doesn't seem realistic that a plausible PDMEDTM and PDSTATE=ON have been entered by mistake while the patient was not under medication. \\ \cmidrule{2-3}
    & Some records have a non-empty PDMEDTM and have PDTRTMNT=0, which is inconsistent.
    & Set PDTRTMNT=1. It is unlikely that a plausible medication time was entered by mistake. \\ \cmidrule{2-3}
    & Some patients were on medication at screening time while PPMI patients were supposed to be unmedicated at screening time.
    & \textbf{Keep the records. Maybe the patients started medication between recruitment and screening time.} \\ \cmidrule{2-3}
    & Some records have PDSTATE=ON but PDMEDTM is after EXAMTM.
    & \textbf{Discard the records.} \\ \cmidrule{2-3}
    & Some visits have 3 exams while a maximum of two exams per visit are expected, one in OFF state and one in ON state.   
    & Remove exam with EXAMTM=NaN and PDSTATE=NaN  when visit has 3 exams \\
    % & &
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT
The first example is changed to a long table with `xltabular`. Currently, `\\*` keeps `Problem`/`Fix` groups together after page breaks. If the latter is not required, simply use a regular `\\` everywhere.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\appendix
\chapter{Data cleaning rules implemented in MDS UPRDS III}
\begingroup
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{p{1.7cm}X}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Inconsistency}} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth] \endhead
    \textbf{Problem:} & Some records have missing data for all UPDRS-III variables. \\*
    \textbf{Fix:}     & Remove these records \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Problem:} & A few records have PDSTATE=ON and PDTRTMNT=0, which is inconsistent: \\*
    \textbf{Fix:}     & Set PDTRTMNT=1 for these records. It doesn't seem realistic that a plausible PDMEDTM and PDSTATE=ON have been entered by mistake while the patient was not under medication. \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Problem:} & Some records have a non-empty PDMEDTM and have PDTRTMNT=0, which is inconsistent. \\*
    \textbf{Fix:}     & Set PDTRTMNT=1. It is unlikely that a plausible medication time was entered by mistake. \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Problem:} & Some patients were on medication at screening time while PPMI patients were supposed to be unmedicated at screening time. \\*
    \textbf{Fix:}     & \textbf{Keep the records. Maybe the patients started medication between recruitment and screening time.} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Problem:} & Some records have PDSTATE=ON but PDMEDTM is after EXAMTM. \\*
    \textbf{Fix:}     & \textbf{Discard the records.} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Problem:} & Some visits have 3 exams while a maximum of two exams per visit are expected, one in OFF state and one in ON state. \\*
    \textbf{Fix:}     & Remove exam with EXAMTM=NaN and PDSTATE=NaN  when visit has 3 exams \\
    \bottomrule
    % & &
  \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I tried to implement your solution and it seems that the table cuts at the bottom of the page. Additionally, an additional blank page is added at the top. Here is a [preview](https://imgur.com/a/L3EQ2FL)

Comment: @turkishcoffee This is normal. Please, see my update. Regular tables get cut if they are too tall and exceed available space. The solution is to change to one of the long tables that can span multiple pages: `longtable` or `xltabular`. The former is equivalent to `tabular`; the latter utilise `X`-type column (similarly to `tabularx`).

Comment: @turkishcoffee You can see your answer was closed due to lack if details. You can also see my answer was incomplete because of wrong assumptions. This is why you should ALWAYS provide [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) to help us help you. Next time, please remember the MWE should be minimal, should demonstrate your problem in question as well as surrounding context. I would probably recommend a long table in the first place.

Comment: hello, thank you for the update, it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

You may liked the following table design:

[image]

For simpler table code I suggest to use `tabularray` package, for better filling of cells use `\small` font size and reduced linespread:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%
\usepackage{geometry}   % added, since your config file is unknow
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % for better (smart) breaking text in table cells
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colsep=4pt, colspec = {@{} X X @{}},
              rowsep = 4pt,
            row{1,2} = {font=\small\bfseries, rowsep=1pt},
            row{3-Z} = {font=\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont, cmd=\RaggedRight}
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=2]{l}    Type: Inconsistency           
        &                               \\
Problem &   Fix                         \\
    \midrule
Some records have missing data for all UPDRS-III variables.
        & Remove these records          \\
A few records have PDSTATE=ON and PDTRTMNT=0, which is inconsistent:
        & Set PDTRTMNT=1 for these records. It doesn't seem realistic that a plausible PDMEDTM and PDSTATE=ON have been entered by mistake while the patient was not under medication. 
                                        \\
Some records have a non-empty PDMEDTM and have PDTRTMNT=0, which is inconsistent.
        & Set PDTRTMNT=1. It is unlikely that a plausible medication time was entered by mistake.
                                        \\
Some patients were on medication at screening time while PPMI patients were supposed to be unmedicated at screening time.
        & \textbf{Keep the records. Maybe the patients started medication between recruitment and screening time.}                          \\
Some records have PDSTATE=ON but PDMEDTM is after EXAMTM. 
        & \textbf{Discard the records.} \\
Some visits have 3 exams while a maximum of two exams per visit are expected, one in OFF state and one in ON state.
        & Remove exam with EXAMTM=NaN and PDSTATE=NaN  when visit has 3 exams   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```